# Improve the speed and shorten the code for excel VBA MACRO

Tags: vba, excel, charts

I am very new on working with VBA and I wrote the code for a macro that initially build 16 charts and then exports the charts in .jpeg format. 
The code is not to difficult to understand. 
There are only some small differences on data to be selected, the name of the charts, and the position of the chart in the workbook. 
Its basically  almost the same code multiplied 16 times for creating charts and another 16 times for exporting them.

The code works fine but is taking around 20- 30 seconds to run.
Do you have any Ideas on how I make it run faster?.

Any input is welcomed. Thank you for your time.

**First part for creating the charts**

```
Sub Export()

Dim objChrt As ChartObject
Dim myChart As Chart
Dim sh As Worksheet

ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Name = "Sheet1"
Set sh = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

'S11-S14
Set mychrt = sh.Shapes.AddChart.Chart
Set chrta = sh.Shapes.AddChart.Chart
Set chrtb = sh.Shapes.AddChart.Chart
Set chrtc = sh.Shapes.AddChart.Chart

'S21-S24
Set chrtd = sh.Shapes.AddChart.Chart
Set chrte = sh.Shapes.AddChart.Chart
Set chrtf = sh.Shapes.AddChart.Chart
Set chrtg = sh.Shapes.AddChart.Chart

'S31-S34
Set chrth = sh.Shapes.AddChart.Chart
Set chrti = sh.Shapes.AddChart.Chart
Set chrtj = sh.Shapes.AddChart.Chart
Set chrtk = sh.Shapes.AddChart.Chart

'S41-S44
Set chrtl = sh.Shapes.AddChart.Chart
Set chrtm = sh.Shapes.AddChart.Chart
Set chrtn = sh.Shapes.AddChart.Chart
Set chrto = sh.Shapes.AddChart.Chart

'/////////S11-S14\\\\\\\\\\\\
With mychrt
'S11
' Chart type and source selection
.ChartType = xlXYScatterSmoothNoMarkers
.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
.SeriesCollection(1).Name = "=Sheet1!$C$5"
.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = "=Sheet1!$B$807:$B$1006"
.SeriesCollection(1).Values = "=Sheet1!$C$807:$C$1006"

' Color
.SeriesCollection(1).Border.ColorIndex = 3 'change to suit

' Titles
.Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
.Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Text = "Gain(dB)"
.Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
.Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Text = "Frequency (Hz)"
.HasTitle = True
.ChartTitle.Text = "S11"

' Scale settings
.Axes(xlCategory).Select
.Axes(xlCategory).MinimumScale = 2400000000#
.Axes(xlCategory).MaximumScale = 2500000000#
.Axes(xlCategory).HasMajorGridlines = True
 Selection.TickLabelPosition = xlLow
.Axes(xlValue).Select
.Axes(xlValue).MinimumScale = -40
.Axes(xlValue).MaximumScale = 0
.Axes(xlValue).HasMajorGridlines = True

' Position and size
.ChartArea.Top = 10
.ChartArea.Left = 1700
.ChartArea.Height = 400
.ChartArea.Width = 750
End With

With chrta
'S12
' Chart type and source selection
.ChartType = xlXYScatterSmoothNoMarkers
.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
.SeriesCollection(1).Name = "=Sheet1!$E$5"
.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = "=Sheet1!$B$807:$B$1006"
.SeriesCollection(1).Values = "=Sheet1!$E$807:$E$1006"

' Color
.SeriesCollection(1).Border.ColorIndex = 43 'change to suit (Green)

' Titles
.Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
.Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Text = "Gain(dB)"
.Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
.Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Text = "Frequency (Hz)"
.HasTitle = True
.ChartTitle.Text = "S12"

' Scale settings
.Axes(xlCategory).Select
.Axes(xlCategory).MinimumScale = 2400000000#
.Axes(xlCategory).MaximumScale = 2500000000#
.Axes(xlCategory).HasMajorGridlines = True
 Selection.TickLabelPosition = xlLow
.Axes(xlValue).Select
.Axes(xlValue).MinimumScale = -40
.Axes(xlValue).MaximumScale = 0
.Axes(xlValue).HasMajorGridlines = True

' Position and size
.ChartArea.Top = 10
.ChartArea.Left = 2460
.ChartArea.Height = 400
.ChartArea.Width = 750
End With

With chrtb
' Chart type and source selection
.ChartType = xlXYScatterSmoothNoMarkers
.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
.SeriesCollection(1).Name = "=Sheet1!$g$5"
.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = "=Sheet1!$B$807:$B$1006"
.SeriesCollection(1).Values = "=Sheet1!$g$807:$g$1006"

' Color
.SeriesCollection(1).Border.ColorIndex = 43 'change to suit

' Titles
.Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
.Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Text = "Gain(dB)"
.Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
.Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Text = "Frequency (Hz)"
.HasTitle = True
.ChartTitle.Text = "S13"

' Scale settings
.Axes(xlCategory).Select
.Axes(xlCategory).MinimumScale = 2400000000#
.Axes(xlCategory).MaximumScale = 2500000000#
.Axes(xlCategory).HasMajorGridlines = True
 Selection.TickLabelPosition = xlLow
.Axes(xlValue).Select
.Axes(xlValue).MinimumScale = -40
.Axes(xlValue).MaximumScale = 0
.Axes(xlValue).HasMajorGridlines = True

' Position and size
.ChartArea.Top = 10
.ChartArea.Left = 3220
.ChartArea.Height = 400
.ChartArea.Width = 750
End With

With chrtc
' Chart type and source selection
.ChartType = xlXYScatterSmoothNoMarkers
.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
.SeriesCollection(1).Name = "=Sheet1!$i$5"
.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = "=Sheet1!$B$807:$B$1006"
.SeriesCollection(1).Values = "=Sheet1!$i$807:$i$1006"

' Color
.SeriesCollection(1).Border.ColorIndex = 43 'change to suit

' Titles
.Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
.Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Text = "Gain(dB)"
.Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
.Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Text = "Frequency (Hz)"
.HasTitle = True
.ChartTitle.Text = "S14"

' Scale settings
.Axes(xlCategory).Select
.Axes(xlCategory).MinimumScale = 2400000000#
.Axes(xlCategory).MaximumScale = 2500000000#
.Axes(xlCategory).HasMajorGridlines = True
 Selection.TickLabelPosition = xlLow
.Axes(xlValue).Select
.Axes(xlValue).MinimumScale = -40
.Axes(xlValue).MaximumScale = 0
.Axes(xlValue).HasMajorGridlines = True

' Position and size
.ChartArea.Top = 10
.ChartArea.Left = 3980
.ChartArea.Height = 400
.ChartArea.Width = 750
End With

'/////////S21-S24\\\\\\\\\\\\

With chrtd
'S21
' Chart type and source selection
.ChartType = xlXYScatterSmoothNoMarkers
.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
.SeriesCollection(1).Name = "=Sheet1!$k$5"
.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = "=Sheet1!$B$807:$B$1006"
.SeriesCollection(1).Values = "=Sheet1!$k$807:$k$1006"

' Color
.SeriesCollection(1).Border.ColorIndex = 41 'change to suit

' Titles
.Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
.Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Text = "Gain(dB)"
.Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
.Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Text = "Frequency (Hz)"
.HasTitle = True
.ChartTitle.Text = "S21"

' Scale settings
.Axes(xlCategory).Select
.Axes(xlCategory).MinimumScale = 2400000000#
.Axes(xlCategory).MaximumScale = 2500000000#
.Axes(xlCategory).HasMajorGridlines = True
 Selection.TickLabelPosition = xlLow
.Axes(xlValue).Select
.Axes(xlValue).MinimumScale = -40
.Axes(xlValue).MaximumScale = 0
.Axes(xlValue).HasMajorGridlines = True

' Position and size
.ChartArea.Top = 420
.ChartArea.Left = 1700
.ChartArea.Height = 400
.ChartArea.Width = 750
End With

With chrte
'S22
' Chart type and source selection
.ChartType = xlXYScatterSmoothNoMarkers
.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
.SeriesCollection(1).Name = "=Sheet1!$m$5"
.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = "=Sheet1!$B$807:$B$1006"
.SeriesCollection(1).Values = "=Sheet1!$m$807:$m$1006"

' Color
.SeriesCollection(1).Border.ColorIndex = 3 'change to suit (Green)

' Titles
.Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
.Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Text = "Gain(dB)"
.Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
.Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Text = "Frequency (Hz)"
.HasTitle = True
.ChartTitle.Text = "S22"

' Scale settings
.Axes(xlCategory).Select
.Axes(xlCategory).MinimumScale = 2400000000#
.Axes(xlCategory).MaximumScale = 2500000000#
.Axes(xlCategory).HasMajorGridlines = True
 Selection.TickLabelPosition = xlLow
.Axes(xlValue).Select
.Axes(xlValue).MinimumScale = -40
.Axes(xlValue).MaximumScale = 0
.Axes(xlValue).HasMajorGridlines = True

' Position and size
.ChartArea.Top = 420
.ChartArea.Left = 2460
.ChartArea.Height = 400
.ChartArea.Width = 750
End With

With chrtf
'S23
' Chart type and source selection
.ChartType = xlXYScatterSmoothNoMarkers
.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
.SeriesCollection(1).Name = "=Sheet1!$o$5"
.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = "=Sheet1!$B$807:$B$1006"
.SeriesCollection(1).Values = "=Sheet1!$o$807:$o$1006"

' Color
.SeriesCollection(1).Border.ColorIndex = 43 'change to suit

' Titles
.Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
.Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Text = "Gain(dB)"
.Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
.Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Text = "Frequency (Hz)"
.HasTitle = True
.ChartTitle.Text = "S23"

' Scale settings
.Axes(xlCategory).Select
.Axes(xlCategory).MinimumScale = 2400000000#
.Axes(xlCategory).MaximumScale = 2500000000#
.Axes(xlCategory).HasMajorGridlines = True
 Selection.TickLabelPosition = xlLow
.Axes(xlValue).Select
.Axes(xlValue).MinimumScale = -40
.Axes(xlValue).MaximumScale = 0
.Axes(xlValue).HasMajorGridlines = True

' Position and size
.ChartArea.Top = 420
.ChartArea.Left = 3220
.ChartArea.Height = 400
.ChartArea.Width = 750
End With

With chrtg
'S24
' Chart type and source selection
.ChartType = xlXYScatterSmoothNoMarkers
.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
.SeriesCollection(1).Name = "=Sheet1!$q$5"
.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = "=Sheet1!$B$807:$B$1006"
.SeriesCollection(1).Values = "=Sheet1!$q$807:$q$1006"

' Color
.SeriesCollection(1).Border.ColorIndex = 43 'change to suit

' Titles
.Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
.Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Text = "Gain(dB)"
.Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
.Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Text = "Frequency (Hz)"
.HasTitle = True
.ChartTitle.Text = "S24"

' Scale settings
.Axes(xlCategory).Select
.Axes(xlCategory).MinimumScale = 2400000000#
.Axes(xlCategory).MaximumScale = 2500000000#
.Axes(xlCategory).HasMajorGridlines = True
 Selection.TickLabelPosition = xlLow
.Axes(xlValue).Select
.Axes(xlValue).MinimumScale = -40
.Axes(xlValue).MaximumScale = 0
.Axes(xlValue).HasMajorGridlines = True

' Position and size
.ChartArea.Top = 420
.ChartArea.Left = 3980
.ChartArea.Height = 400
.ChartArea.Width = 750
End With

'/////////S31-S34\\\\\\\\\\\\

With chrth
'S31
' Chart type and source selection
.ChartType = xlXYScatterSmoothNoMarkers
.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
.SeriesCollection(1).Name = "=Sheet1!$s$5"
.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = "=Sheet1!$B$807:$B$1006"
.SeriesCollection(1).Values = "=Sheet1!$s$807:$s$1006"

' Color
.SeriesCollection(1).Border.ColorIndex = 41 'change to suit

' Titles
.Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
.Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Text = "Gain(dB)"
.Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
.Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Text = "Frequency (Hz)"
.HasTitle = True
.ChartTitle.Text = "S31"

' Scale settings
.Axes(xlCategory).Select
.Axes(xlCategory).MinimumScale = 2400000000#
.Axes(xlCategory).MaximumScale = 2500000000#
.Axes(xlCategory).HasMajorGridlines = True
 Selection.TickLabelPosition = xlLow
.Axes(xlValue).Select
.Axes(xlValue).MinimumScale = -40
.Axes(xlValue).MaximumScale = 0
.Axes(xlValue).HasMajorGridlines = True

' Position and size
.ChartArea.Top = 830
.ChartArea.Left = 1700
.ChartArea.Height = 400
.ChartArea.Width = 750
End With

With chrti
'S32
' Chart type and source selection
.ChartType = xlXYScatterSmoothNoMarkers
.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
.SeriesCollection(1).Name = "=Sheet1!$u$5"
.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = "=Sheet1!$B$807:$B$1006"
.SeriesCollection(1).Values = "=Sheet1!$u$807:$u$1006"

' Color
.SeriesCollection(1).Border.ColorIndex = 41 'change to suit (Green)

' Titles
.Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
.Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Text = "Gain(dB)"
.Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
.Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Text = "Frequency (Hz)"
.HasTitle = True
.ChartTitle.Text = "S32"

' Scale settings
.Axes(xlCategory).Select
.Axes(xlCategory).MinimumScale = 2400000000#
.Axes(xlCategory).MaximumScale = 2500000000#
.Axes(xlCategory).HasMajorGridlines = True
 Selection.TickLabelPosition = xlLow
.Axes(xlValue).Select
.Axes(xlValue).MinimumScale = -40
.Axes(xlValue).MaximumScale = 0
.Axes(xlValue).HasMajorGridlines = True

' Position and size
.ChartArea.Top = 830
.ChartArea.Left = 2460
.ChartArea.Height = 400
.ChartArea.Width = 750
End With

With chrtj
'S33
' Chart type and source selection
.ChartType = xlXYScatterSmoothNoMarkers
.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
.SeriesCollection(1).Name = "=Sheet1!$w$5"
.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = "=Sheet1!$B$807:$B$1006"
.SeriesCollection(1).Values = "=Sheet1!$w$807:$w$1006"

' Color
.SeriesCollection(1).Border.ColorIndex = 3 'change to suit

' Titles
.Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
.Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Text = "Gain(dB)"
.Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
.Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Text = "Frequency (Hz)"
.HasTitle = True
.ChartTitle.Text = "S33"

' Scale settings
.Axes(xlCategory).Select
.Axes(xlCategory).MinimumScale = 2400000000#
.Axes(xlCategory).MaximumScale = 2500000000#
.Axes(xlCategory).HasMajorGridlines = True
 Selection.TickLabelPosition = xlLow
.Axes(xlValue).Select
.Axes(xlValue).MinimumScale = -40
.Axes(xlValue).MaximumScale = 0
.Axes(xlValue).HasMajorGridlines = True

' Position and size
.ChartArea.Top = 830
.ChartArea.Left = 3220
.ChartArea.Height = 400
.ChartArea.Width = 750
End With

With chrtk
'S34
' Chart type and source selection
.ChartType = xlXYScatterSmoothNoMarkers
.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
.SeriesCollection(1).Name = "=Sheet1!$y$5"
.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = "=Sheet1!$B$807:$B$1006"
.SeriesCollection(1).Values = "=Sheet1!$y$807:$y$1006"

' Color
.SeriesCollection(1).Border.ColorIndex = 43 'change to suit

' Titles
.Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
.Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Text = "Gain(dB)"
.Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
.Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Text = "Frequency (Hz)"
.HasTitle = True
.ChartTitle.Text = "S34"

' Scale settings
.Axes(xlCategory).Select
.Axes(xlCategory).MinimumScale = 2400000000#
.Axes(xlCategory).MaximumScale = 2500000000#
.Axes(xlCategory).HasMajorGridlines = True
 Selection.TickLabelPosition = xlLow
.Axes(xlValue).Select
.Axes(xlValue).MinimumScale = -40
.Axes(xlValue).MaximumScale = 0
.Axes(xlValue).HasMajorGridlines = True

' Position and size
.ChartArea.Top = 830
.ChartArea.Left = 3980
.ChartArea.Height = 400
.ChartArea.Width = 750
End With

'/////////S41-S44\\\\\\\\\\\\

With chrtl
'S41
' Chart type and source selection
.ChartType = xlXYScatterSmoothNoMarkers
.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
.SeriesCollection(1).Name = "=Sheet1!$AA$5"
.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = "=Sheet1!$B$807:$B$1006"
.SeriesCollection(1).Values = "=Sheet1!$AA$807:$AA$1006"

' Color
.SeriesCollection(1).Border.ColorIndex = 41 'change to suit

' Titles
.Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
.Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Text = "Gain(dB)"
.Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
.Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Text = "Frequency (Hz)"
.HasTitle = True
.ChartTitle.Text = "S41"

' Scale settings
.Axes(xlCategory).Select
.Axes(xlCategory).MinimumScale = 2400000000#
.Axes(xlCategory).MaximumScale = 2500000000#
.Axes(xlCategory).HasMajorGridlines = True
 Selection.TickLabelPosition = xlLow
.Axes(xlValue).Select
.Axes(xlValue).MinimumScale = -40
.Axes(xlValue).MaximumScale = 0
.Axes(xlValue).HasMajorGridlines = True

' Position and size
.ChartArea.Top = 1240
.ChartArea.Left = 1700
.ChartArea.Height = 400
.ChartArea.Width = 750
End With

With chrtm
'S42
' Chart type and source selection
.ChartType = xlXYScatterSmoothNoMarkers
.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
.SeriesCollection(1).Name = "=Sheet1!$ac$5"
.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = "=Sheet1!$B$807:$B$1006"
.SeriesCollection(1).Values = "=Sheet1!$ac$807:$ac$1006"

' Color
.SeriesCollection(1).Border.ColorIndex = 41 'change to suit (Green)

' Titles
.Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
.Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Text = "Gain(dB)"
.Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
.Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Text = "Frequency (Hz)"
.HasTitle = True
.ChartTitle.Text = "S42"

' Scale settings
.Axes(xlCategory).Select
.Axes(xlCategory).MinimumScale = 2400000000#
.Axes(xlCategory).MaximumScale = 2500000000#
.Axes(xlCategory).HasMajorGridlines = True
 Selection.TickLabelPosition = xlLow
.Axes(xlValue).Select
.Axes(xlValue).MinimumScale = -40
.Axes(xlValue).MaximumScale = 0
.Axes(xlValue).HasMajorGridlines = True

' Position and size
.ChartArea.Top = 1240
.ChartArea.Left = 2460
.ChartArea.Height = 400
.ChartArea.Width = 750
End With

With chrtn
'S43
' Chart type and source selection
.ChartType = xlXYScatterSmoothNoMarkers
.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
.SeriesCollection(1).Name = "=Sheet1!$ae$5"
.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = "=Sheet1!$B$807:$B$1006"
.SeriesCollection(1).Values = "=Sheet1!$ae$807:$ae$1006"

' Color
.SeriesCollection(1).Border.ColorIndex = 41 'change to suit

' Titles
.Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
.Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Text = "Gain(dB)"
.Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
.Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Text = "Frequency (Hz)"
.HasTitle = True
.ChartTitle.Text = "S43"

' Scale settings
.Axes(xlCategory).Select
.Axes(xlCategory).MinimumScale = 2400000000#
.Axes(xlCategory).MaximumScale = 2500000000#
.Axes(xlCategory).HasMajorGridlines = True
 Selection.TickLabelPosition = xlLow
.Axes(xlValue).Select
.Axes(xlValue).MinimumScale = -40
.Axes(xlValue).MaximumScale = 0
.Axes(xlValue).HasMajorGridlines = True

' Position and size
.ChartArea.Top = 1240
.ChartArea.Left = 3220
.ChartArea.Height = 400
.ChartArea.Width = 750
End With

With chrto
'S44
' Chart type and source selection
.ChartType = xlXYScatterSmoothNoMarkers
.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
.SeriesCollection(1).Name = "=Sheet1!$ag$5"
.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = "=Sheet1!$B$807:$B$1006"
.SeriesCollection(1).Values = "=Sheet1!$ag$807:$ag$1006"

' Color
.SeriesCollection(1).Border.ColorIndex = 3 'change to suit

' Titles
.Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
.Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Text = "Gain(dB)"
.Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
.Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Text = "Frequency (Hz)"
.HasTitle = True
.ChartTitle.Text = "S44"

' Scale settings
.Axes(xlCategory).Select
.Axes(xlCategory).MinimumScale = 2400000000#
.Axes(xlCategory).MaximumScale = 2500000000#
.Axes(xlCategory).HasMajorGridlines = True
 Selection.TickLabelPosition = xlLow
.Axes(xlValue).Select
.Axes(xlValue).MinimumScale = -40
.Axes(xlValue).MaximumScale = 0
.Axes(xlValue).HasMajorGridlines = True

' Position and size
.ChartArea.Top = 1240
.ChartArea.Left = 3980
.ChartArea.Height = 400
.ChartArea.Width = 750
End With
```

**Second part for exporting the charts**

```
Set objChrt = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(1)
Set myChart = objChrt.Chart
myFileName = ActiveWorkbook.Name & " " & "S11.JPEG"
On Error Resume Next
Kill ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & myFileName
On Error GoTo 0
myChart.Export Filename:=ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & myFileName, Filtername:="JPEG"

Set objChrt = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(2)
Set myChart = objChrt.Chart
myFileName = ActiveWorkbook.Name & " " & "S12.JPEG"
On Error Resume Next
Kill ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & myFileName
On Error GoTo 0
myChart.Export Filename:=ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & myFileName, Filtername:="JPEG"

 Set objChrt = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(3)
Set myChart = objChrt.Chart
myFileName = ActiveWorkbook.Name & " " & "S13.JPEG"
On Error Resume Next
Kill ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & myFileName
On Error GoTo 0
myChart.Export Filename:=ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & myFileName, Filtername:="JPEG"

 Set objChrt = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(4)
Set myChart = objChrt.Chart
myFileName = ActiveWorkbook.Name & " " & "S14.JPEG"
On Error Resume Next
Kill ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & myFileName
On Error GoTo 0
myChart.Export Filename:=ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & myFileName, Filtername:="JPEG"

 Set objChrt = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(5)
Set myChart = objChrt.Chart
myFileName = ActiveWorkbook.Name & " " & "S21.JPEG"
On Error Resume Next
Kill ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & myFileName
On Error GoTo 0
myChart.Export Filename:=ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & myFileName, Filtername:="JPEG"

Set objChrt = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(6)
Set myChart = objChrt.Chart
myFileName = ActiveWorkbook.Name & " " & "S22.JPEG"
On Error Resume Next
Kill ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & myFileName
On Error GoTo 0
myChart.Export Filename:=ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & myFileName, Filtername:="JPEG"

Set objChrt = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(7)
Set myChart = objChrt.Chart
myFileName = ActiveWorkbook.Name & " " & "S23.JPEG"
On Error Resume Next
Kill ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & myFileName
On Error GoTo 0
myChart.Export Filename:=ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & myFileName, Filtername:="JPEG"

Set objChrt = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(8)
Set myChart = objChrt.Chart
myFileName = ActiveWorkbook.Name & " " & "S24.JPEG"
On Error Resume Next
Kill ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & myFileName
On Error GoTo 0
myChart.Export Filename:=ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & myFileName, Filtername:="JPEG"

Set objChrt = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(9)
Set myChart = objChrt.Chart
myFileName = ActiveWorkbook.Name & " " & "S31.JPEG"
On Error Resume Next
Kill ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & myFileName
On Error GoTo 0
myChart.Export Filename:=ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & myFileName, Filtername:="JPEG"

Set objChrt = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(10)
Set myChart = objChrt.Chart
myFileName = ActiveWorkbook.Name & " " & "S32.JPEG"
On Error Resume Next
Kill ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & myFileName
On Error GoTo 0
myChart.Export Filename:=ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & myFileName, Filtername:="JPEG"

 Set objChrt = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(11)
Set myChart = objChrt.Chart
myFileName = ActiveWorkbook.Name & " " & "S33.JPEG"
On Error Resume Next
Kill ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & myFileName
On Error GoTo 0
myChart.Export Filename:=ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & myFileName, Filtername:="JPEG"

 Set objChrt = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(12)
Set myChart = objChrt.Chart
myFileName = ActiveWorkbook.Name & " " & "S34.JPEG"
On Error Resume Next
Kill ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & myFileName
On Error GoTo 0
myChart.Export Filename:=ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & myFileName, Filtername:="JPEG"

 Set objChrt = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(13)
Set myChart = objChrt.Chart
myFileName = ActiveWorkbook.Name & " " & "S41.JPEG"
On Error Resume Next
Kill ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & myFileName
On Error GoTo 0
myChart.Export Filename:=ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & myFileName, Filtername:="JPEG"

Set objChrt = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(14)
Set myChart = objChrt.Chart
myFileName = ActiveWorkbook.Name & " " & "S42.JPEG"
On Error Resume Next
Kill ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & myFileName
On Error GoTo 0
myChart.Export Filename:=ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & myFileName, Filtername:="JPEG"

Set objChrt = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(15)
Set myChart = objChrt.Chart
myFileName = ActiveWorkbook.Name & " " & "S43.JPEG"
On Error Resume Next
Kill ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & myFileName
On Error GoTo 0
myChart.Export Filename:=ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & myFileName, Filtername:="JPEG"

Set objChrt = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(16)
Set myChart = objChrt.Chart
myFileName = ActiveWorkbook.Name & " " & "S44.JPEG"
On Error Resume Next
Kill ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & myFileName
On Error GoTo 0
myChart.Export Filename:=ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & myFileName, Filtername:="JPEG"

MsgBox "OK"

End Sub
```

Comment: maybe you can track down which part of the code is taking up the most time?

Comment: if all your charts are similar then you should start by creating a Sub which creates the charts: pass in parameters for the variable parts of each chart. The resulting code will be easier to optimize...

Comment: + 1 @TimWilliams: Bullseye :)

Comment: I don't think there will be a speed improvement by replacing repetitive lines of code with loops.  The only thing that might yield a small improvement is `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` (just make sure you have  `Application.ScreenUpdating = True` at the end).

Comment: You could try saving the Excel file as HTML instead of exporting the charts individually. That way, all the charts will be saved at once in PNG format. See if that's faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your 1st sub has `556` lines of code just to create 16 charts. That is the most inefficient way of writing code. Imagine if you would have to create 100 charts?

Your code can be summarized in approx `60` lines.

**Logic:**

1. Use a loop to create a chart.
2. See a pattern and assign variables for it. For example `Chart.Left` or the `Chart.Name` or `.SeriesCollection(1).Name` or `.SeriesCollection(1).Values` etc.
3. I have not used `Application.ScreenUpdating = False`. You could use that as well to increase the speed of the code.

**Code: (UNTESTED)**

```
Sub Export()
    Dim objChrt As ChartObject
    Dim myChart As Chart
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim startCol As Long, ChrtNo As Long, lftChart As Long
    Dim ColName As String

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Name = "Sheet1"
    Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)

    strtCol = 3 '<~~ Col C
    ChrtNo = 11
    lftChart = 1700

    For i = 1 To 16
        Set mychrt = sh.Shapes.AddChart.Chart

        ColName = Split(sh.Cells(, strtCol).Address, "$")(1)
        With mychrt
            ' Chart type and source selection
            .ChartType = xlXYScatterSmoothNoMarkers
            .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
            .SeriesCollection(1).Name = "=Sheet1!$" & ColName & "$5"
            .SeriesCollection(1).XValues = "=Sheet1!$B$807:$B$1006"
            .SeriesCollection(1).Values = "=Sheet1!$" & ColName & "$807:$" & ColName & "$1006"

            ' Color
            .SeriesCollection(1).Border.ColorIndex = 43 'change to suit (Green)

            ' Titles
            .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
            .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Text = "Gain(dB)"
            .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
            .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Text = "Frequency (Hz)"
            .HasTitle = True
            .ChartTitle.Text = "S" & ChrtNo

            ' Scale settings
            .Axes(xlCategory).Select
            .Axes(xlCategory).MinimumScale = 2400000000#
            .Axes(xlCategory).MaximumScale = 2500000000#
            .Axes(xlCategory).HasMajorGridlines = True
             Selection.TickLabelPosition = xlLow
            .Axes(xlValue).Select
            .Axes(xlValue).MinimumScale = -40
            .Axes(xlValue).MaximumScale = 0
            .Axes(xlValue).HasMajorGridlines = True

            ' Position and size
            .ChartArea.Top = 10
            .ChartArea.Left = lftChart
            .ChartArea.Height = 400
            .ChartArea.Width = 750
        End With

        strtCol = strtCol + 2
        ChrtNo = ChrtNo + 1
        lftChart = lftChart + 760
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: I tested the code you posted and is working good. I still need to add some lines to fit my tasks. Now I can use the method described  by the users above and put in practice by you. The run time speed also improved. Thank you all for your posts.